# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with apt upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, segmentation-fault

Ubuntu 19.04, upgraded from 18.04.

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco
```

It has been working and updating fine since I started running the PC in May (bought it with Ubuntu pre-installed and manually upgraded from there). I go on holiday for a week or so, and come back and the update does this:

```
root@charles-H310M:/home/charles# apt update && apt upgrade
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/damentz/liquorix/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                    
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease                                                                         
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                  
Hit:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease                                                                       
Ign:7 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:8 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                         
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                       
Get:10 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu cosmic Release [6,600 B]                                                                           
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                            
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                      
Ign:13 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                                                                                
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                   
Hit:15 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                                                                      
Hit:16 http://archive.canonical.com disco InRelease                                                                           
Hit:17 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                 
Hit:18 https://wavebox.pro/dl/client/repo x86_64/ InRelease
Fetched 6,600 B in 1s (5,433 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
47 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Stats '[ ! -f /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-hook ] || /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-hook'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

So it seems the offending package is ubuntu-advantage-tools but I am hesitant to purge it as it is part of the ubuntu-minimal package which sounds kinda important.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Segmentation fault usually means a bug in the application. Please [report it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) on Launchpad.

Comment: Not sure why this is deemed off-topic. I had the same problem and fixed it by `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-advantage-tools`.

Comment: @RobHyndman yes! that solved 4me same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** so the answer was to run 'apt upgrade' as my command was using an && so not reaching that part.

---

Whilst not strictly an answer, it would appear that the standard Software Updater GUI application is able to process this all fine. That slightly irks/worries me.

So my 'answer' to my own problem is to use the Software Updater GUI.

Comment: It would probably have been equally effective to run `apt upgrade`. That part of your command `apt update && apt upgrade` didn't run, because `apt update` failed (in this case by crashing), and `&&` is short-circuiting, running its right-hand command only after its left-hand command succeeds. You can probably continue to use the command line for package management if you want. (This still isn't a solution to the underlying problem of how to explain or prevent the crash, of course.)

Comment: Oh man, I didn't think of that; I just presumed it was the upgrade part. What a terrible assumption!